# Connect 12 Led 3 switch

Tags: led, switches, led-driver

I want to connect 12 LEDs with 3 switches. 
First switch to turn on 4 LEDs.
Second 8 LEDs.
Third switch to turn on all LEDs.
I don't know what kind of switch to use and the schematic.

Comment: Use a 3P4S LED matrix with current limiting R to define the current in each switched string of 4. What supply you choose should be in the 12-14Vdc range depends on how bright ( current) and how long if on a battery and the power ratings of the LEDs Each switch uses a diode to the group of 4 in series or 2 or 3 groups being selected.

Comment: what colours and mA?  Or is this academic?

Comment: @ElcRiv Please clarify your question, maybe post a block diagram or use the circuit editor

Comment: pls define LED and input voltage avail

Comment: Voltage for led its 220 V converter by the led itself to 12V(recessed lights). Led its 3W. I will mount it on ceiling and i want to turn it on side by side 4 with one switch and 8 with second switch . The third switch to turn all the led. What kind off accesories should i use Relay switch etc.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGKW1I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Three-switch circuit. D13 and 14 prevent cross-feed from one circuit to the other.*

---

[Late information supplied in the comments.]

> Voltage for led its 220 V converter by the led itself to 12V. I will mount it on ceiling and i want to turn it on side by side 4 with one switch and 8 with second switch .

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFLTZk.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Mains version.*

For domestic wiring regular wall mounted light switches should be used that comply with the electrical regulations of your country.

- SW1 and SW2 are regular single-pole switches.
- SW3 is a 2-pole switch.
- You do not require relays or accessories.

Again, it is not clear why you want SW3 when you can have the same effect by switching on SW1 and SW2. It seems likely to lead to confusion.

Of more concern is that if you are asking this question then you are unlikely to be qualified to perform the installation. You may wish to reconsider taking on this project and get professional help instead.

Comment: Unless they are ganged radio buttons so only one is on at a time, there's not much point in having SW3 (a requirements oddity rather than a criticism of your solution).

Comment: if SW1 and SW2 are on , then SW3 is redundant (all)

Comment: OP's requirement: "_Third switch to turn on all led._" I didn't write it! ;*)

Comment: Voltage for led its 220 V converter by the led itself to 12V. I will mount it on ceiling and i want to turn it on side by side 4 with one switch and 8 with second switch . The third switch to turn all the led. What kind off accesories should i use Relay switch etc.
Thank you

Comment: @ElcRiv: You need to supply that information **in the question** and not in the comments. Can you explain why you want a third switch? Nobody here can understand why you can't just turn on the 4 and 8 switches to get all to turn on.

Answer (score 0):

ipad cant finish adding lines and add 2nd diode to middle SW and 3 diodes to Third SW.

This allows you to run white LEDs on a car 12V system with Schottky diodes and suitable R for 14.2V like 5-10 Ohms for 5mm.

But you shud define input V and current per LED.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKG9v4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>